# git desktop client doesn't show all remote branches

Tags: git

My understanding was that these two commands should show me all remote branches

```
git branch -a
git branch -r
```

but when I execute these two commands, I don't see a branch which was created very recently.

I can see this branch in the web user interface. but not when I do `git branch -a`

Even though I can see this branch in the web UI. when I try to do

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/branch feature/branch it says

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/feature/branch' does not exist
```

funny thing is that if I delete my local directory and do a `git clone` again then it can see the new branch.

Does anyone know why does the git command line client cannot see the new branch?

Comment: What web user interface do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git only communicates over the network at very specific commands.  Otherwise it's using a *local, cached copy* of any remote repositories.  When you run `git branch -r` it is this local cache that is being checked.  `origin/feature/branch` is a "remote tracking branch" in your local cache.  So your local copy of the remote is simply out of date.

To update, run [`git fetch [remote-name]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).  This is a totally safe operation and will not affect your local branches, it will just bring your local cache into sync with the remote.  `git pull` will also update as it is basically a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`, but then you have to worry about the merge.

Comment: I wouldn't use "cache" like that in the context of Git; it's too likely to be confused with the *index*.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a little on @Schwern answer. Almost every operation in Git is local. Unless told it never checks for remote changes. Your local copy has a database which is stored inside the .git folder. When you run commands like `git branch -a` it checks with the local db and not the remote itself.

That's why whenever there is a change on the remote you need to update this local database to the get the latest updates and `git fetch` does this. It only updates your local git db without making any modification to the code itself.

Answer (score -2):

This happens to me frequently. To solve, I just run `git pull`, so git becomes aware of the new branch.